# How to place title in the middle of image in ion slides in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

[image]

Here is my html template of my image and header I want to align t text in side that image

```
  <ion-slides   *ngIf="getData.length>0" autoplay="2700" speed="300" class="slideroption" pager="true" loop="true"> 
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of getData" (click)="openItem(item)"> 
  <img src="{{item.jetpack_featured_media_url}}" class="new-collection"/> 
      <h4  [innerHTML]="item.title.rendered"></h4>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ion-card

**html**

```
<ion-slides   *ngIf="getData.length>0" autoplay="2700" speed="300" class="slideroption" pager="true" loop="true"> 
   <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of getData" (click)="openItem(item)"> 
     <ion-card class="myCard">
       <img src="{{item.jetpack_featured_media_url}}" class="new-collection"/> 
         <div class="myOverlay">
           <div class="card-title">{{ item.title.rendered }}</div>
           <div class="card-subtitle">{{ some subtitle you like }}</div>
         </div>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-slide>
 </ion-slides>
```

And some styling

**css**

```
img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.myCard{
  position:relative;

}

.myOverlay{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  padding-top:5%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  bottom: 20%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: black;
}
```

[Working-demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-y84acs)

Comment: How to set  style background for header

Comment: Could you be more specific, please? Which header are you talking about? And does the solution I have given works for your requirement?

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I got the image on my text but the text can't be seen because of image so I want the header background to be black and the text should be visible. Thanks

Comment: I have edited the post according to the requirement as well as the working demo. Feel free to play with the property like the bottom, height.padding-top etc in the CSS

Comment: Loved it, Thanks